# Hashem's name missing in Shir Hashirim

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, megillat-esther, shir-hashirim

Why is Hashem's name missing in Shir Hashirim? The haggadah is so specific in mentioning Hashem's name over and over and instead leaves out Moshe's name (except one time). I'm wondering why then Hashem's name is missing in the megillah we read on the same holiday? I've heard many answers in regards to the purim megillah and how it had to be a nes nistar vs the Haggadah wants to make it clear its a nes nigleh and all from Hashem. But what is the reason Hashem's name is missing in Shir Hashirim?

Comment: I would assume the answer is for the same reason God's name is not mentioned in Esther: it never shows up. And this book is even shorter than Esther.

Comment: All in all 2 out of 24 books is not that odd. Some other books don't have shem havaya, some don't have shem elohut. What's the big deal?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.5.17

Comment: Is there a particular reason you would expect His name to appear? Does the content not make sense without it?

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi Binyamin Shmueli says on Hidabroot](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/31304) that the reason Hashem's name is  not found in Shir Hashirim is since it is a song of love between Hashem and the Jewish nation it is written in a way that people will not be jealous of this special relationship.

> כל שיר השירים כתוב בצורת סוד וברמיזה ולכן גם שם ה' לא כתוב. זהו שיר
> אהבה של הקב"ה לעם ישראל ולהיפך  והשיר נכתב בצורה עדינה שלא יקנאו בנו
> אחרים.

Comment: If you have time, an english translation of the quoted portion would help out those of us still learning Hebrew, to use an understatement heh. If anyone does translate, please @ me so I get notified otherwise I may not see it since Im new to stackexchange and it didnt even seem to notify me when people commented in my own questions.

Comment: @ShipBuilding if you want to be notified of edits to this post, just click "Follow" beneath it.

Comment: @Shipbuilding the translation is in the answer that I wrote. I placed the quote to show what my answer is based on.